# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\.......'

Tags: asp.net, .net, delete-file

When I want to clear the contents from a folder in ASP.NET, I keep on getting this error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'E:.....'.

This is the exception:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'E:...'.

This is the code

```
Dim directory As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("users/temporary/" & CStr(Session("Nickname"))))
            Empty(directory)
```

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Comment: That's the complete message in the exception? Perhaps it's being truncated in the display and you need to expand it?

Comment: no, its the full path, but i didn't want it on the internet. But i am very sure the path is correct

Comment: I hope people can't set their nickname to `../..`

Comment: Either the path is wrong, or `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` is broken. I'm inclined to suspect that the former is true. Perhaps you should `Dim myPath as String = Server.MapPath(...)` and make sure it's doing what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

can you execute a test to check if the path exists? Like this:

```
var myPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
if (Directory.Exists(myPath)) {
    //put a break point
}
```